# How to suspend/resume a process using vbscript

Tags: process, vbscript, resume, suspend

Is there a way to suspend and resume a process using vbscript? Currently I created an input box that terminates a processes but instead of terminating it is there a way to just suspend it?

```
'Terminate all processes involving the name <strProcessToKill>
Option Explicit
Dim strComputer, strProcessToKill, objWMIService, colProcess, objProcess

strComputer = "."
strProcessToKill = InputBox("Process to kill","Userinput")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
   & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
   & strComputer _ 
   & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
   ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & strProcessToKill & "'")
For Each objProcess in colProcess
   msgbox "... terminating " & objProcess.Name
   objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't suspend or resume a process from VBScript via a scripting API. You have to shell out to something like [`pssuspend`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540) for this kind of task.